# php error and dropdown needs fixing

Tags: php, drop-down-menu

Below is the "Room" table in the database:

```
   Room          Building            Capacity
    CW5/10        Canalside West        50
    CW4/09        Canalside West        40
    CW2/08        Canalside West        40
    CW4/10        Canalside West        25
    CE1/03        Canalside East        40
```

I am getting this error:

> Notice: Undefined index: Rooms in /web/stud/u0867587/Mobile_app/create_session.php on line 374

which is for this code:

```
foreach ($buildings[0]['Rooms'] as $roomId => $roomData)
```

So my question is how can the error be fixed (I believe it is because it is trying to find 0 even though my values for building is Canalside East and Canalside West).

Below is the full code:

```
  $sql="SELECT Building, Room FROM Room WHERE Building = '".$building."'";

    $sqlresult = mysql_query($sql);

    $buildings = array(); // easier if you don't use generic names for data

    while($sqlrow = mysql_fetch_array($sqlresult))
    {
        // you need to initialise your building array cells
        if (!isset($buildings[$sqlrow['Building']])) {
            $buildings[$sqlrow['Building']] = array('Rooms' => array());
        }

        // you can add the room to the building 'Rooms' array
        $buildings[$sqlrow['Building']]['Rooms'][] = $sqlrow['Room'];
    }


    $buildingHTML = ""; 
    $buildingHTML .= '<select name="buildings" id="buildingssDrop">'.PHP_EOL;
    $buildingHTML .= '<option value="">Please Select</option>'.PHP_EOL; 

    foreach ($buildings as $building => $buildingData) {      
        $buildingHTML .= "<option value='".$building."'>" . $building . "</option>".PHP_EOL;        
    }
    $buildingHTML .= '</select>';

    $roomHTML = ""; 
    $roomHTML .= '<select name="rooms" id="roomsDrop">'.PHP_EOL;
    $roomHTML .= '<option value="">Please Select</option>'.PHP_EOL;      
    foreach ($buildings[0]['Rooms'] as $roomId => $roomData) {        
        $roomHTML .= "<option value='".$roomId."'>" . $roomId . "</option>".PHP_EOL;        
    } 

    $roomHTML .= '</select>';
```

How can I get the dropdown menus to work so that it displays a list a buildings for one dropdown menu and in second dropdown it will display the list of rooms which belongs to the selected building from the first drop down menu. At the moment this code displays 2 dropdown menus, both only containing the option "Please Select".

Comment: Reading between the lines of what you seem to be doing, I think you probably want to generate the `rooms` select dynamically based on what is selected in the `buildings` select. If this is the case, you are best not trying to do both in the same call, and using AJAX to retrieve the data after the user has selected a value for `buildings`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do a lot more in order to get this working as you said (ie, when you select one building you can select the rooms for that building). The difficulty is that PHP is not aware of what you have selected on the page once it has rendered the content.

You can certainly get the second dropdown to display rooms from a specific building:

On this line:

```
$buildings[$sqlrow['Building']]['Rooms'][] = $sqlrow['Room'];
```

You set the index to 'Building', not 0. For this reason, `$buildings[0]...` is, as the error says, undefined. If you change the foreach to:

```
foreach ($buildings[<building name goes here>]['Rooms'] as $roomId => $roomData) {        
    $roomHTML .= "<option value='".$roomId."'>" . $roomId . "</option>".PHP_EOL;        
}
```

Should work.

However, to get the page to update the second dropdown after the first has been changed you'd need to either use AJAX or make the first dropdown post a response back to the page with a value, maybe something as simple as this:

```
$buildingname = $_POST['buildings'];
foreach ($buildings[$buildingname]['Rooms'] as $roomId => $roomData) {        
    $roomHTML .= "<option value='".$roomId."'>" . $roomId . "</option>".PHP_EOL;        
}
```

You'd then need to add in a submit button to submit the first select, or possibly some javascript to submit the form when the selected item is changed -

```
$buildingHTML .= '<select name="buildings" id="buildingssDrop" onchange="document.getElementById(\'dropDownForm\').submit()">'.PHP_EOL;
```

You'd then need to wrap the first select in form tags, with attributes in the opening tag of -

```
<form action="" method="post">
```

And hopefully, if you got through all of that rather badly explained code, you should have something working!

(Full code - untested - in case my explanation is too difficult to follow: http://pastebin.com/9UGx8nTX)

Comment: The string of the key is not `Building`, it is `Canalside West` (or whatever)

Comment: Good point, I missed that...will edit in a second to reflect that. It'd probably be better to rewrite a lot more code than just this loop with that in mind, though

Comment: Updated to give an unpleasant way to achieve what was actually asked. Thanks for bringing that to my attention, @DaveRandom.

Comment: Hi, It is giving me 2 notices: 
Notice: Undefined index: buildings in /web/stud/u0867587/Mobile_app/create_session.php on line 377 which is `$buildingname = $_POST['buildings'];`

Notice: Undefined index: in /web/stud/u0867587/Mobile_app/create_session.php on line 378 which is `foreach ($buildings[$buildingname]['Rooms'] as $roomId => $roomData)`

Comment: Oops, it would do that prior to a post...you'll need to check for a post first of all. You just need to surround the last foreach loop and the line above within an if statement: `if(isset($_POST['buildings'])){` and it should run ok.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this solution will address your problem:

```
function simpleOptionBuilder($description) {
  return sprintf('<option>%s</option>'$description);
}

// ... some other code here

$sql="SELECT Building, Room FROM Room WHERE Building = '".$building."'";
$sqlresult = mysql_query($sql);

$buildings = array(); // easier if you don't use generic names for data
while($sqlrow = mysql_fetch_array($sqlresult))
{
    // you need to initialise your building array cells
    if (!isset($buildings[$sqlrow['Building']])) {
        $buildings[$sqlrow['Building']] = array('Rooms' => array());
    }

    // you can add the room to the building 'Rooms' array
    $buildings[$sqlrow['Building']]['Rooms'][] = $sqlrow['Room'];
}


$buildingHTML = ""; 
$buildingHTML .= '<select name="buildings" id="buildingssDrop">'.PHP_EOL;
$buildingHTML .= '<option value="">Please Select</option>'.PHP_EOL; 
join(PHP_EOL, array_map('simpleOptionBuilder', array_keys($buildings));
$buildingHTML .= '</select>';

$roomHTML = ""; 
$roomHTML .= '<select name="rooms" id="roomsDrop">'.PHP_EOL;
$roomHTML .= '<option value="">Please Select</option>'.PHP_EOL;      

$firstRow = reset($buildings);
join(PHP_EOL, array_map('simpleOptionBuilder', $firstRow['Rooms']);
$roomHTML .= '</select>';
```

I've encapsulated the option formatter into a function, and contestually removed the
value attribute of the option tag. You don't need it as value and description are the same.

For the first select you need the Buildings names and I think you can leverage on array_keys to leverage on this.

The second select should be the contains, if I'm right, the rooms belongings to the building selected into the first one.

If you want the first row of an hash array you can use the [reset function](http://php.net/reset) and I've coded this solution. There is an issue, though.

If the first select shows the *Please Select* option then the second select should be empty. You need to recover the selected option from the $_GET, $_POST or $_REQUEST arrays and leverage on that value to fill the second post. You can change the code accordingly.

```
// similar code above 
$selectedBuilding = $_REQUEST['buildings'];
if (isset($buildings[$selectedBuilding]) {
    join(PHP_EOL, array_map('simpleOptionBuilder', 
                            $buildings[$selectedBuilding]['Rooms']
                  )
    );
}
$roomHTML .= '</select>';
```

EDIT: Further Encapsulation

```
function simpleSelectBuilder($id, $name, $default, $optionArray) {
    $result =  '<select name="' . $name . '" id="'. $id .'">'.PHP_EOL
       . '<option value="">Please Select</option>'.PHP_EOL 
       .  join(PHP_EOL, array_map(
                'simpleOptionBuilder', 
                 $optionArray, array_fill(0,count($optionArray), $default))
          )
            .  '</select>';
}

function simpleOptionBuilder($description, $selectThisValue) {
  $selectedAttribute = $value==$selectThisValue?'selected':'';
  return sprintf('<option %s>%s</option>', $selectedAttribute, $description);
}

function param($name) {
    if (isset($_REQUEST[$name])) {
        return $_REQUEST[$name];
    }
    return null;
}


// ... some other code here

$sql="SELECT Building, Room FROM Room WHERE Building = '".$building."'";
$sqlresult = mysql_query($sql);

$buildings = array(); // easier if you don't use generic names for data
while($sqlrow = mysql_fetch_array($sqlresult))
{
    // you need to initialise your building array cells
    if (!isset($buildings[$sqlrow['Building']])) {
        $buildings[$sqlrow['Building']] = array('Rooms' => array());
    }

    // you can add the room to the building 'Rooms' array
    $buildings[$sqlrow['Building']]['Rooms'][] = $sqlrow['Room'];
}

$selectedBuilding = param('buildings'); // TODO: sanity check
$selectedRoom = param('rooms'); // TODO: sanity check

$buildingHTML = simpleSelectBuilder(
    'buildingssDrop',
    'buildings',
    $selectedBuilding,
    array_keys($building)
); 

$roomHTML = simpleSelectBuilder(
    'roomsDrop',
    'rooms',
    $selectedRoom,
    $buildings[$selectedBuilding]['Rooms']
);
```

Now the problem should be clearer: Retrieve the input data and update the select accordingly. You can add a submit request to the first select onchange event (simpler solution) or deploy a full ajax solution but this is out of the question topic to me.

Comment: Way nicer than my suggestion, +1.

Comment: @user1163005 Beware, there are several typos in the code (I'm just coding in the edit box here in stackoverflow) you have to handle. By the way I've addedd a cleaner solution