# List of Buildings and Rooms not appearing in dropdown list

Tags: php

Below is the "Room" table in the database:

```
   Room          Building            Capacity
    CW5/10        Canalside West        50
    CW4/09        Canalside West        40
    CW2/08        Canalside West        40
    CW4/10        Canalside West        25
    CE1/03        Canalside East        40
```

Below is the full code:

```
           <?php

foreach (array('courseid','building') as $varname) {
    $$varname = (isset($_POST[$varname])) ? $_POST[$varname] : '';
  }

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $query = "
                 SELECT cm.CourseId, cm.ModuleId, 
                 c.CourseName,
                 m.ModuleName
                 FROM Course c
                 INNER JOIN Course_Module cm ON c.CourseId = cm.CourseId
                 JOIN Module m ON cm.ModuleId = m.ModuleId
                 WHERE
                 (c.CourseId = '".mysql_real_escape_string($courseid)."')
                 ORDER BY c.CourseName, m.ModuleId
                 ";

    $num = mysql_num_rows($result = mysql_query($query));

    if($num ==0){
        echo "<p>Sorry, No Course was found with this Course ID '$courseid'</p>";
    } else { 

        $dataArray = array();

        session_start();

        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 
            $dataArray[$row['CourseId']]['CourseName'] = $row['CourseName']; 
            $dataArray[$row['CourseId']]['Modules'][$row['ModuleId']]['ModuleName'] = $row['ModuleName']; 

$_SESSION['idcourse'] = $row['CourseId'];
$_SESSION['namecourse'] = $row['CourseName'];

    }

     foreach ($dataArray as $courseId => $courseData) {

          $output = ""; 

          $output .= "<p><strong>Course:</strong> " . $courseId .  " - "  . $courseData['CourseName'] . "</p>";

       $moduleHTML = ""; 
       $moduleHTML .= '<select name="module" id="modulesDrop">'.PHP_EOL;
       $moduleHTML .= '<option value="">Please Select</option>'.PHP_EOL;      
            foreach ($courseData['Modules'] as $moduleId => $moduleData) {        

            $moduleHTML .= "<option value='".$moduleId.' '.$moduleData['ModuleName']."'>" . $moduleId . " - " . $moduleData['ModuleName'] ."</option>".PHP_EOL;        
  } 
            }
            $moduleHTML .= '</select>';

      echo $output;
```

//Above is course and module, below is buildings and room  (All code is in one `<?php?>` tag.

```
 $sql="SELECT Building, Room FROM Room WHERE Building = '".$building."'";

    $sqlresult = mysql_query($sql);

    $buildings = array(); // easier if you don't use generic names for data

    while($sqlrow = mysql_fetch_array($sqlresult))
    {
        // you need to initialise your building array cells
        if (!isset($buildings[$sqlrow['Building']])) {
            $buildings[$sqlrow['Building']] = array('Rooms' => array());
        }

        // you can add the room to the building 'Rooms' array
        $buildings[$sqlrow['Building']]['Rooms'][] = $sqlrow['Room'];
    }


    $buildingHTML = ""; 
    $buildingHTML = "<form action=\"\" method=\"post\">";
    $buildingHTML .= '<select name="buildings" id="buildingssDrop" onchange="document.getElementById(\'dropDownForm\').submit()">'.PHP_EOL;
    $buildingHTML .= '<option value="">Please Select</option>'.PHP_EOL; 

    foreach ($buildings as $building => $buildingData) {      
        $buildingHTML .= "<option value='".$building."'>" . $building . "</option>".PHP_EOL;        
    }
    $buildingHTML .= '</select>';
    $buildingHTML .= '</form>';

    $roomHTML = ""; 
    $roomHTML .= '<select name="rooms" id="roomsDrop">'.PHP_EOL;
    $roomHTML .= '<option value="">Please Select</option>'.PHP_EOL; 

    if(isset($_POST['buildings'])){
        $buildingname = $_POST['buildings'];
    foreach ($buildings[$buildingname]['Rooms'] as $roomId => $roomData) {        
        $roomHTML .= "<option value='".$roomId."'>" . $roomId . "</option>".PHP_EOL;        
    }
}
    $roomHTML .= '</select>';


        ?>
```

Now in the top half of the script it controls the course and module. The user enters in a CourseId and if it is wrong, it will display a message stating no course if found, if it is correct it will display the course name and then it will display a dropdown menu which contains the list of modules that belongs to that course. This works fine.

The bottom half of the code is the problem. It is suppose to display 2 drop down menus, one dropdown will show a list a buildings and in second dropdown it will display the list of rooms which belongs to the selected building from the first drop down menu. At the moment this code displays 2 dropdown menus, both only displaying the option "Please Select" and nothing else.

As some of the experts have pointed out, they believe the problem is that the `$building` variable contains null. How is it suppose to work so that the $building variable is able to retrieve the list of buildings from the query?

You can view the application [here](http://helios.hud.ac.uk/u0867587/Mobile_app/create_session.php) Type in 'info101' for the courseId and submit it, you will see all the features appear. Go onto the module dropdown list and you will see the modules associated with the course. If you look at the Building and Room Dropdown menu, they both only display "Please Select".

Comment: print_r($buildings) show's something? Maybe your query dont return data...

Comment: I tested query in mysql (minus the WHERE clause) and it return the data there. I wil try your print method and see what is displays

Comment: Almost complete duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9032123/php-error-and-dropdown-needs-fixing - seems to be my answer from that question with no alterations the code at all. Why not just use that question?

Comment: It prints out 'Array ()', so I am pretty sure it is not finding the list of buildings, why is this?

Comment: The where makes a lot of difference.  Print $sql to see.

Comment: Hi, Hecksa, it is you answer I am using but I cannot go onto my original account because Opera can not find the stackoverflow server and I have forgot what my login details are for that SO account so I am using my Internet explorer SO (backup) account to ask this question. I would have referred back to that  question and asked you for help but I can't access that account so I can't add comments on that question. Sorry :(

Comment: The print($sql) shows 'SELECT Building, Room FROM Room WHERE Building = '' '

Comment: Where does `$building` come from at the top of the script, anyway?

Comment: $building is set on top from this:     `foreach (array('courseid','building') as $varname) {
        $$varname = (isset($_POST[$varname])) ? $_POST[$varname] : '';
      }`

Comment: courseid which becomes $courseid works because it is a textbox where user type in a course, if course is in database then it displays all of the other features, if not then it displays a message saying 'We can't find course'

Comment: Then that's our problem - when I wrote the additions to make the above work I didn't realise there was another form posting to the page. That's going to cause issues - edit the question to show the whole script you have and we might have a better chance at fixing this.

Comment: Ok give me 5 mins to edit the script above

Comment: Google jquery dynamic dropdown box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change your PHP code to acheive this scenario. If you want the rooms to be dynamical populated when changing the building name you can user jquery. Include jQUery library in your script.You need to do an ajax call to dynamically populate the list.

I have added only from building part. Rest all above is same. In the foreach loop remove the building from the array.Change your current php code to this.

PHP CODE:

```
 $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT Building FROM Room";

 $sqlresult = mysql_query($sql);

 $buildings = array(); // easier if you don't use generic names for data

 $buildingHTML = ""; 
 $buildingHTML = "<form action=\"\" method=\"post\">";
 $buildingHTML .= '<select name="buildings" id="buildingssDrop" onchange="getRooms();">'.PHP_EOL;
 $buildingHTML .= '<option value="">Please Select</option>'.PHP_EOL; 

 while($sqlrow = mysql_fetch_array($sqlresult))
 {
     $building = $sqlrow['Building'];
     $buildingHTML .= "<option value='".$building."'>" . $building . "</option>".PHP_EOL; 
  }

  $buildingHTML .= '</select>';
  $buildingHTML .= '</form>';

  $roomHTML = ""; 
  $roomHTML .= '<select name="rooms" id="roomsDrop">'.PHP_EOL;
  $roomHTML .= '<option value="">Please Select</option>'.PHP_EOL; 
  $roomHTML .= '</select>';

  echo $buildingHTML; 
  echo $roomHTML;
```

You need to add a script for dynamic population.

JS CODE:

```
function getRooms() {
    var building = jQuery("#buildingssDrop").val();
    jQuery('#roomsDrop').empty();
    jQuery('#roomsDrop').html('<option value="">Please Select</option>');
    jQuery.ajax({
          type: "post",
          url:  "rooms.php",
          data: "building="+building,
          success: function(response){
              jQuery('#roomsDrop').append(response);
          }
        });
 }
```

Here the rooms.php is the ajax file you need to call for dynamic population of data:

rooms.php

```
$building = isset($_POST['building']) ? $_POST['building'] : '';
$sql = "SELECT Room FROM Room WHERE Building ='".$building."'";

$sqlresult = mysql_query($sql);


$roomHTML  = ""; 

while($sqlrow = mysql_fetch_array($sqlresult))
{
     $room = $sqlrow['Room'];
     $roomHTML .= "<option value='".$room."'>" . $room . "</option>".PHP_EOL; 
}


echo $roomHTML;
```

Hope this helps for you

Comment: I will test this and get back to you, I really do appreciate the effort and help you are giving me btw :)

Comment: Hi, This has worked great :). You said you have only added building part so in php do I just set the roomsHtml coding to be similar like the buildingHtml coding so that the rooms list will appear in the dropdown. Upvoted and best answer :)

Comment: I just meant that i am doing the part from the building HTML. All the codes above it are correct. Sorry if my words were misleading. The current code is correct no need of any changes.

Comment: +1 for taking the time to write the whole thing out, wish I'd done that at the start rather than trying to get a quick fix for the question.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the post value for the building is set.

since you told that the sql output shows no value for the building parameter, it is sure that $building will be null. You need to pass the post value to the $building

You need to change your code like this:

```
if(isset($_POST['buildings'])){
    $building = $_POST['buildings'];
} else {
   $building = '';
}

$sql="SELECT Building, Room FROM Room WHERE Building = '".$building."'";

$sqlresult = mysql_query($sql);

$buildings = array(); // easier if you don't use generic names for data

while($sqlrow = mysql_fetch_array($sqlresult))
{
    // you need to initialise your building array cells
    if (!isset($buildings[$sqlrow['Building']])) {
        $buildings[$sqlrow['Building']] = array('Rooms' => array());
    }

    // you can add the room to the building 'Rooms' array
    $buildings[$sqlrow['Building']]['Rooms'][] = $sqlrow['Room'];
}


$buildingHTML = ""; 
$buildingHTML = "<form action=\"\" method=\"post\">";
$buildingHTML .= '<select name="buildings" id="buildingssDrop" onchange="document.getElementById(\'dropDownForm\').submit()">'.PHP_EOL;
$buildingHTML .= '<option value="">Please Select</option>'.PHP_EOL; 

foreach ($buildings as $building => $buildingData) {      
    $buildingHTML .= "<option value='".$building."'>" . $building . "</option>".PHP_EOL;        
}
$buildingHTML .= '</select>';
$buildingHTML .= '</form>';

$roomHTML = ""; 
$roomHTML .= '<select name="rooms" id="roomsDrop">'.PHP_EOL;
$roomHTML .= '<option value="">Please Select</option>'.PHP_EOL; 

if(isset($_POST['buildings'])){
    $buildingname = $_POST['buildings'];
     foreach ($buildings[$buildingname]['Rooms'] as $roomId => $roomData) {        
           $roomHTML .= "<option value='".$roomId."'>" . $roomId . "</option>".PHP_EOL;        
     }
}
$roomHTML .= '</select>';


echo $buildingHTML;

echo $roomHTML;
```

Comment: Still the same, no difference, still shows 2 dropdown menus that only options in both is "Please Select and that is all

Comment: Are you sure the $_POST['buildings'] has some value inside it. Try printing . print_r($_POST);

Comment: I did your print and this is what it prints: Array ( [courseid] => info101 [submit] => Submit ) , it doesn't print anything from Buildings?

Comment: So your post does not contain the value of the building. So only you were getting only Please Select output. Can you tell me how are you passing the building value to the page.

Comment: How are you getting the $building variable in your sql

Comment: $building is set on top from this: `foreach (array('courseid','building') as $varname) { $$varname = (isset($_POST[$varname])) ? $_POST[$varname] : ''; } `

Comment: courseid which becomes $courseid works because it is a textbox where user type in a course, if course is in database then it displays all of the other features, if not then it displays a message saying 'We can't find course' does it work differently when display a value in a dropdown list than it is typing in a value in a textbox?

Comment: I included full php script in my edit btw, hopefully this wud help u

Comment: Here in the first for loop you are setting $bulding with a value from $_POST['building'] but the $_POST doesn't contain a value with index 'building'. Can you make sure your $_POST contains the index with value building

Comment: so do I suppose to write $building = $_POST['building']? to get the $_POST to contain the index with value building?

Comment: But in the post parameters you printed early there is no index named building. So how can we get that value from post. Is there any relation between course id and building.. The problem is $building is empty and you are assigning $building value from $_POST['building'] but there is no index named building in your post. Hope you understand

Comment: no I understand that, what i meant was how can I assign $building to contain a list of buuildings from the database? there is no relation between coruseid and building by the way, I hought by displaying them on top in the foreach loop, it will assign them php cariables ($ in front of courseid and building) to make it php variable

Comment: Can you tell me which is the table which contains all the buildings

Comment: The 'Room' table, The Room table and its field is in on top of my question and the Sql can be seen in the php script in my edit